# Sufficient conditions for unitarity of a representation of a Lie Superalgebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, physics, lie-superalgebras, supersymmetry

Suppose we have a Lie superalgebra with triangular decomposition:
\begin{equation}
\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{g}^{+} \oplus \mathfrak{g}^{0} \oplus \mathfrak{g}^{-}
\end{equation}

I've seen it stated in a few places that a sufficient condition for unitarity of a lowest weight representation of a lie superalgebra formed from quotienting out null states is just checking that all states in
\begin{equation}
U(\mathfrak{g}_1^{+})v_{\lambda}
\end{equation}
have positive norm, where $v_{\lambda}$ is the lowest weight state, and $\mathfrak{g}_1^{+}$ are the fermionic raising operators. I'm using the candidate inner product given by setting $<v_{\lambda}, v_{\lambda}> =1$ and computing all other norms in the inner product by using the (anti)commutation relations of the algebra.

An example paper for reference: https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0201076.pdf (section 2.6).

I can't see why this is true. All I can see is that this condition would imply that there is a basis of the Verma module, each of which with positive norm.

Answer (score 1):

If i have correctly understood your question, i think that the answer can be found at

M. D. Gould, R. B. Zhang, [Classification of all star and grade star irreps of gl(n|1)](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.528695), J. of Math. Phys., 31, 1524 (1990).

See particularly Lemma 2, p. 1526 and the following discussion (esp. at the end of p. 1527).
(I think the authors there use the term "*star representations*" as identical to "*unitary representations*").

Comment: Hi Konstantinos, sorry for the late reply, I’ve been knocked out of action for a little while. Maybe I just don’t understand the paper, but I cannot see where it is justified that it is sufficient to check that all states generated by odd elements in the superalgebra have positive norm?